# Renderflex overflow - how do I overcome this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I know I will get a lot of negative remarks for this question, but I'm getting really frustrated. 
I tested my app on a new iPhone 11pro and I get now a lot of renderflex errors. You all know the error logs - and even google give you some advice like " Have you considered using a Flex or Expanded parent?  "

Now, for Text Widgets that go over, I use Expanded. .. and that's great. That's super! I just wrap my Text in an Expanded and it "wraps" the text around so it fits within its container.

But what would be the equivalent of wrapping other widgets like rows or columns, or singlechildscrollviews?

I tried to wrap them in an expanded, and I get the same error message.

I'm fed up.

Here is an example of some code:

```
            Container(
             // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
             // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,


              //TODO: checkboxes

              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(width: 200,height: 100,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          checkbox(sun, days[sun]),
                          checkbox(mon, days[mon]),
                          checkbox(tue, days[tue]),
                          checkbox(wed, days[wed]),
                          checkbox(thu, days[thu]),
                          checkbox(fri, days[fri]),
                          checkbox(sat, days[sat]),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
          ),
```

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are facing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1 :** Use `ListView`

```
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 100,
                  child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text("Example"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
         ),
```

[image]

**Approach 2 :** You can use `Wrap` instead of `ListView` if you want show all items in that child.